Print lines based on two column values
I have a two columns file like this (the second column is sorted) :
m       8569
=       8569
u       8569
j       8569
=       8570
m       8570
j       8570
c       8570
j       8571
j       8572
j       8573
n       8573
=       8573
m       8573
c       8573
u       8574
u       8574

I need to print the lines for which the value in col1 is "u" , but only when this value is associated to all the same values in col2. I should get :
u       8574
u       8574

For example, that does not work here because the "u" value is associated to the "8569" value but there are also  the "m" , "=" and "j" values :
m       8569
=       8569
u       8569
j       8569

I also try to deal with this issue (awk group by and print if matches a condition) but I get stuck to get the lines that match only the character "u".
Best

please update the question with your coding attempt(s) and the (wrong) results generated by your code

Do you need number of lines with u       8574 exactly equal to number of such lines in input file or you can accept single u       8574 as output?

I can accept single line output.

If you care about preserving the white space between the 2 fields then [edit] your question to tell us what that white space is - a tab or some number of blanks or something else.

Using GNU awk for arrays-of-arrays
gawk '
    { data[$2][$1][NR] = $0 }
    END {
        for (val in data)
            if ("u" in data[val] && length(data[val]) == 1)
                for (nr in data[val]["u"])
                    print data[val]["u"][nr]
    }
' file

outputs
u   8574
u   8574

But if you only need to print unique instances, we can save some memory
gawk '
    { data[$2][$1] = 1 }
    END {
        OFS = "\t"
        for (val in data)
            if ("u" in data[val] && length(data[val]) == 1)
                print "u", val
    }
' file


With your shown samples please try following awk.
awk 'match($0,/^u[[:space:]]+[0-9]+$/){line=$0} !arr[line]++ && line' Input_file


If you don't care about white space then using any uniq+awk:
$ uniq -c file | awk '($2 == "u") && ($1 > 1){for (i=1; i<=$1; i++) print $2, $3}'
u 8574
u 8574

If you do care:
$ uniq -c file | awk '($2 == "u") && ($1 > 1){n=$1; sub(/^ *[^ ]+ /,""); for (i=1; i<=n; i++) print}'
u       8574
u       8574

Change it to sort file | uniq -c | awk '...' if your real input isn't already grouped by values like your example.

another variant (using GNU Awk 5.0.1)
Handles standard ascii and dos formatted records
cat pablo.awk
{ gsub("\r",""); k[$1" "$2] = k[$1" "$2] + 1 }
END{
        for (ki in k)
                if ( k[ki] > 1 )
                        print ki
}

# running that produces
awk -f pablo.awk input
u   8574 


gsub("\r","") would remove desirable as well as undesirable \rs, you should be using sub(/\r$/,"") instead to just remove the \rs at the end of lines.

@EdMorton, maybe, but not in this case afaics. dos formatted ascii is 'typically' records ending as you've indicated \r$ ... never come across them in any other format, but appreciate the feedback tks.

You're welcome. The thing is, depending on the input, sub(/\r$/,"") will always work while gsub("\r","") will only usually work so I can't think of any reason to favor gsub("\r",""). Your choice of course.
